# Is the River Sarasvati from Rig Veda Mandala 6 an Afghani River?

Tags: rig-veda, saraswati, geography

I've seen claims that apparently the oldest Sarasvati of Mandala 6 is actually from Afghanistan, how accurate is this claim?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prove or disprove such claims. You have mentioned the Sarasvati hymn in Rig Veda VI.61. There is another mention of Sarasvati in Book 7.

> This stream Sarasvati with fostering current comes forth, our sure
> defence, our fort of iron, as on a car, the flood flows on, surpassing
> in majesty and might all other waters;

**Rig Veda VII.95.1**

> **Pure in her course from mountain to the ocean**, alone of her streams
> Sarasvati has listened. Thinking of wealth and the great world of
> creatures, she poured for Nahusa her milk and fatness.

**Rig Veda VII.95.2**

Sarasvati cannot possibly be an Afghan river if she flows to the ocean. However, scholars like Witzel and historian like Irfan Habib have claimed that ocean means here a big lake.

The answer to the question is it all depends on how you interpret the word 'ocean'.

Comment: What about the claim that Sarasvati's description not matching with Indian GH river but matching with Hemland river? i asked book 6 specifically because it's older.

Comment: How can one prove or disprove such a claim? Moreover why should it matter that book 6 is older than book 7? Sarasvati river was flowing to the ocean in older times and stopped flowing at later times. So the fact that book 7 is later than 6 and Sarasvati was flowing to the ocean at later time suggests that Sarasvati was flowing to the ocean during Book 6 also. Of course one way to solve the problem is to say that there are 2 Sarasvati rivers. This will also be another unprovable claim. Also it violates Occam's razor.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay we know most of the Vedas were located in north India such claims are false.